# Why Elsevier Journals don't change status of a paper?

Tags: peer-review

> Why  Elsevier Journals don't change status of a paper?

I am new to this publishing world and I don't have much knowledge in this field.
I am Junior Researcher.

I communicated only one paper until now  in Elsevier Journal.

My question is "Do Elsevier Journals not change status of a manuscript"?

I have submitted my manuscript nearly 5 months back and it is still showing the status "With Editor"

I am kinda confused whats going on.

How will a researcher come to know about its status?

I did mail the Editor two times but got no reply.

What should I do? Should I continue waiting and hope that one day I will get some reply and status will change?

Do all Elsevier Journals keep the same status from Day 1 until acceptance which is "With Editor"?

Comment: There are around 1,700 Elsevier journals.  I doubt there is any answer that applies to "Elsevier journals" in general.

Comment: Make sure to check your spam filters in case they blocked the editor's reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See also: [What does the typical workflow of a journal look like?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like)

- Of course Elsevier journals change their status when there's an update. "With Editor" is one of the earliest statuses, and not progressing is a bad sign.
- You "come to know" about the paper's status by looking at its status. It's "With Editor" right now.
- You didn't say which editor you emailed, although not getting a reply is another bad sign, of course. Did you email the journal office, the editor-in-chief, the handling editor, etc? Whichever you emailed, try emailing a different editor.
- Considering it's been months and the editor apparently hasn't invited reviewers, waiting is not a good idea. Email the other editors, or withdraw your paper and submit elsewhere.

Comment: I had mailed the editor in chief of that journal and also the Associate Editor but got no reply

Comment: Same thing, mail one of the others (in this case, the journal office).

Comment: There is no email address of the journal office provided

Comment: There is only one address provided and that of the editor in chief